# Upgrading iOS and appium version in Device Farm

Tags: aws-device-farm

Can we upgrade the iOS and appium version on Device farm AWS. Can we use existing devices onto cloud ?

Answer (score 0):

I work for the AWS Device Farm team.

Thank you for the feedback. 
While we certainly get the importance of updating to the latest and greatest version of Appium on our part whenever we update the version we make sure all versions of OS and make/models undergo a thorough extensive test. This is a work in progress and you should see the Appium version updated soon.

As far as devices go it is on the same lines where we make sure that we are able to offer the same experience across all devices. We are working on getting the latest iOS devices in our fleet right now and this should be very soon in coming week or two.

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: As far as my knowledge goes , Device farm does not provide with latest iOS version, the appium thats mentioned in device farm was 1.4.XX and we at office use 1.5.3 which supports of multiple devices on a single computer

Comment: We’re heads down on iOS 10 support (and Android N) as we speak.
As for framework versions, we’re considering a couple models going forward so that developers aren’t limited to the framework version we have.  Until then, we evaluate framework versions based on stability and customer demand.

Comment: I see in website that you guys use Appium V 1.4.13 where as we use 1.5.3; would you guys be able to upgrade the appium version ?

Comment: We are testing out the latest version of Appium internally. There is no fixed ETA for this yet. However it is high on our priority list. 
Do you mind me asking if you are missing anything specific if you use Appium 1.4.13 until we get this in ?

Comment: @NikeofTime: THe desired capabilities used are dependent of Appium version

Answer (score 0):

As far as my knowledge goes , Device farm does not provide with latest iOS version, the appium thats mentioned in device farm was 1.4.XX and we at office use 1.5.3 which supports of multiple devices on a single computer